# How to make second regex match take priority?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a PHP variable in a MySQL query, but for some reason I'm still capturing the end-quote (`"`) that ends the query. The problem is that I can't just exclude quote marks because I need to allow for arrays.

**Regex:** `/(?:where)?.*[.| ](?<phrase>(?<col>[a-z_]+).*?(?<opp>=|in)[\s(]*?["'\s.{]+(?<var>\$[^\s;}]+)["'\s.]*)(?<end>.*)/i`

**String:** `$sql = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE id = $uuid";`

**Desired Match:**

- "phrase" - `id = $uuid` (actual match: `id = $uuid"`)

  - "col" - `id`
  - "opp" - `=`
  - "var" - `$uuid` (actual match: `$uuid"`)
- "end" - `";` (actual match: `;`)

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/h0PSZZ/2)

I've included an array in the link to show what I mean. And that one is matching correctly. But I can't figure out how to make the `$uuid` query match without breaking the `array` query. The issue I'm running into is that anything that fixes the `$uuid` query moves the match in the `array` query from `$_REQUEST["user-id"]` to `$_REQUEST["user-id`.

**Is there any way to tell regex to not match the closing quote (if it exists) unless its part of an array parameter?**

As best as I can figure, I need the `<end>` group to take precedence over the `<phrase>` group when matching quote marks, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change 2 things in your pattern. You could add a double quote if you also want to match that in the first part and remove the double quote in the last part if you don't want to add it to the match

```
[\s(]*?["'\s.{]+(?<var>\$[^\s;"}]+)['\s.]*)(?<end>.*)
        ^ Add "                     ^ remove "
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L6uPLK/1)

To match from an opening double quote till a closing double quote in group var, you could update the var group to:

```
(?<var>\$(?:[^"\s;}]+|"[^"\s;]+")*)(?<end>.*)
```

- `(?<var>` Named capturing group `var`

  - `\$` Match `$` char
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `[^"\s;}]+` [Negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), match any character that is not in the character class
    - `|` Or
    - `"[^"\s;}]+"` Match `"`, match 1+ times any char not in the char list, match `"`
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close group `var`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L6uPLK/5)

Comment: This completely breaks the match if the string has an array variable though. https://regex101.com/r/L6uPLK/2